# How to get test id from vstest logger?

Tags: c#, vstest

I'm looking for the id of the test which is run by `vstest.console.exe`. I created custom logger by implementing the `ITestLogger` interface from the assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel` and created three handlers.

```
[ExtensionUri("logger://SimpleLogger")]
    [FriendlyName("SimpleLogger")]
    public class SimpleConsoleLogger : ITestLogger
    {
        public void Initialize(TestLoggerEvents events, string testRunDirectory)
        {
            events.TestRunMessage += TestMessageHandler;

            events.TestResult += TestResultHandler;

            events.TestRunComplete += TestRunCompleteHandler;
        }

        private void TestMessageHandler(object sender, TestRunMessageEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TestResultHandler(object sender, TestResultEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TestRunCompleteHandler(object sender, TestRunCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

But non of these event arguments contains test id. So I'm confused, because when I run my tests with `/Logger:trx` attribute, I can see the test id in the `.trx` file. How can I get it with my custom logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The, `TestResultEventArgs` class has a property named [`Result`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/c701070abb126853b58800cedd7554482471ac7d/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/Logging/Events/TestResultEventArgs.cs#L38), which is of type `TestResult`, that in turn has a property named [`TestCase`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/73aeb4a63e49556bcef78dbcfc86e369ff93e940/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/TestResult.cs#L51) of the same type. That type carries all the information about the test (e.g. the [Id](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/0a7475c1bd93746f8144252f2bf459e1ea2c3bb7/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/TestCase.cs#L88), the `DisplayName`, the `Source`, ...).

In summary:

```
    private void TestResultHandler(object sender, TestResultEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.TestCase.Id);
    }
```